# What are some good resources on symmetry?

Tags: education, book-recommendation, symmetry

I find symmetry very appealing so I would politely ask you for some of the best resources (books, courses, articles, etc.) you know on this topic.

I would also dare to pose a challenge for the most intuitive explanation of some complex practical case symmetry is addressing.

I'm not that well versed with the subject, so anything is welcomed. I also hope this post will remain a future reference for all the people interested in this subject.

Comment: a short book, Hermann Weyl's "Symmetry"

Answer (score 0):

The Symmetries of Things
by John H. Conway, Heidi Burgiel, Chaim Goodman-Strauss

This is an extraordinary book with some great illustrations and includes the 17 wallpaper groups (for example) explained in an accessible way, as well as moving on to more challenging concepts.

Answer (score 0):

*Symmetry* by Hermann Weyl is considered a classic.  Weyl considers symmetry in nature and art as well as in mathematics.